# Deploy war file into tomcat inside VPS

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I'm trying to add a war file to the tomcat inside a VPS and not working at the moment.
I have watched a tutorial to setup the tomcat and i think a have the part inside the VPS working.

The tomcat opens with the GUI in the web. And connecting with the ip of the VPS.

I also added the inside the class that has the main file in it.

```
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(DaiApplication.class);
    }
```

But when i'm trying to upload to deploy the war file it doesn't run to me.

This is what shows when i try open to access some path of the api:

[Printscreen of the 404 error that appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VdXS0.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be an issue with your endpoint, take a look in your "logs" directory  (should be in $catalina_home/$catalina_base next to your "webapps" directory).

Else are you using Spring Version <= 5 ? Don't use Tomcat 10.xx.xx yet, try the latest Tomcat 9.xx.xx, Tomcat 10 uses Jakarta 9EE and the package names changed from javax.* to jakarta.* .  [the primary package for all implemented APIs has changed from javax.* to jakarta.*](https://tomcat.apache.org/download-10.cgi)  .

Comment: Thanks dude, I was using version 2.6.4, i installed the version 9 of the tomcat inside the VPS and it worked.